# Template return type deduction from lvalue?

Tags: c++, templates

This might be a silly question but I would like to have it clarified none the less. Lets say I have a template function like so:

```
template<class T> T getValue(const char *key) const;
```

that returns the value as `T` from internal storage where it is stored under `key` (and possibly as type T already).

Now in order to use this I need to specify the template return type `T` in the function call, for example:

```
int value = getValue<int>("myKey");
```

while what I would want it to do is deduce the template argument from the context, specifically the `lvalue` like so:

```
int value = getValue("myKey"); //getValue<int>() is instantiated with int being deduced automatically from lvalue
```

but I am guessing that this is not possible but I am rather fuzzy as to why. I know using `auto` would make it impossible for the compiler to deduce the template type but why this is as well?

Comment: template instantiation can only deduce its parameters from the arguments to given templated object(function in this case) so no, the variable type does not matter in deducing, and you either have to prove dummy argument to the function or hardcode it as you did in the second to last script code.

Comment: Straightforward answer, thanks. Would you care reposting it as the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It is possible to provide something similar by returning a proxy object which has a `template<class T> operator T() const;` conversion function. That conversion function can deduce the type `T` because there needs to be a conversion between the proxy object's type and the `int value`. This breaks with `auto`, of course, since that will simply store the proxy object (it is possible to make the proxy object noncopyable & nonmovable, but `auto&&` and `auto const&` will still work).

Comment: @dyp This is really interesting idea! I have just tested it out and it works like a charm. Since I am going to use this on limited number of types only I can even get rid of the templates altogether and just spell out the operator() overloads for each type I need. This is certainly a nice alternative indeed. I wonder if the overhead of the proxy object is worth it but that is another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template instantiation can only deduce its parameters from the arguments to given templated object(function in this case) so no, the variable type does not matter in deducing, and you either have to provide dummy argument of type T to the function or hardcode it as you did in the second to last script code(`getValue<int>(...)`).

There is a possible workaround using type deduction presented in the comments :

```
#include <iostream>

namespace byte_read {
    //this is a hack to deduce the type using implicit conversion
    struct type_converter {
        const char* buffer;

        template<typename T>
            operator T() {
            std::cout << "implicit convertion from " << typeid(buffer).name() 
                << " to " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
            //casting memory to the desired type
            return static_cast<T>(*buffer);
        }
    };
    type_converter getValue(const char * buffer) {
        //here buffer is implicitly converted to T type using the operator T()
        return {buffer};
    }

}
using namespace byte_read;

int main()
{
    char buffer[]{0,1,0,0 //int 256 encoded
                  ,97      //char 'a' encoded
                 };
    //pointer to read the buffer sequentialy
    char* pos = buffer;
    //pointer used to count the bytes readed
    char* last_pos = pos;

    int int_256 = getValue(pos);
    pos+=sizeof(int);
    std::cout << int_256 << " bytes readed :" << pos - last_pos << std::endl;

    last_pos = pos;
    char char_a = getValue(pos);
    pos+=sizeof(char);
    std::cout << char_a << " bytes readed :" << pos - last_pos << std::endl;

}
```

You can try it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/v7TdlfQehCc9rBJG)