# Return type deduction from bytes to fundamental types

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a read function that can read bytes from a vector and convert them to fundamental types.

Creating a template may not be the best option but I did not find a better one. I found a similar but different topic [Template return type deduction from lvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554442/template-return-type-deduction-from-lvalue).

In short it means writing `int test = read(it);` instead of `int test = read<int>(it);` in the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>>
T read(std::vector<char>::const_iterator& it) {
    T v;
    char* p = (char*)&v;
    for (size_t i=0; i < sizeof(T); i++) {
        *(p+i) = *(it++);
    }
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> v{0,0,0,1};
    std::vector<char>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
    auto begin = it;
    int test = read<int>(it);

    std::cout << test << " bytes readed :" << std::distance(begin,it) << std::endl;

}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/OSlrZw3cGKoNrMqb

Comment: How is your question different? As far as I can see you are asking the exact question you linked to.

Comment: I'll be the one bringing the bad news: this is not possible. You could define a function to call like this `int test; read(it, test);` but I'm not sure thi sis prefered over `auto test = read<int>(it);`.

Comment: @Darhuuk the difference is that here I got a code problem, I don't precisely look for using template.

Comment: There's [this solution](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dbBl5YD4AS0bhB1P) which is mentioned in the duplicate's comments, and was actually well-received by the OP there, but hasn't been made into an answer...

Comment: @Quentin this is a working but not really readable solution.

Comment: @Pierrot well, you won't get anything better because C++ determines types inside-out :)

Comment: @Quentin if this is the only option I'll try to make it more readable, thanks it makes sense 'C++ determines types inside-out'.

Comment: I just wrote down a small code to make it more readable (at least for me) if someone needs it https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dkha7IbhwBRNVx3f