# What is the correct way to return a template lambda function?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, functional-programming

I am experimenting with lambda functions in C++, and I'd like to make a function that is roughly equivalent to the `take` function in Haskell.

```hs
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

Given an integer `n`, and a list containing any type `a`, it returns a the first `n` elements of the list. I'm attempting to do this with a curried function in C++, but running into issues with making it polymorphic. The current non-polymorphic implementation I have is this:

```cpp
function<vector<int>(vector<int>)> take(int n) {
  return [=](vector<int> v) {
    v.resize(n);
    return v;
  };
}
```

This obviously only works for `vector<int>` types, and I'm wondering how I can make it polymorphic in the type of the vector elements. So far, I've tried some variations of this code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
function<vector<T>(vector<T>)> take(int n) {
  return [=](vector<T> v) {
    v.resize(n);
    return v;
  };
}
```

But when I then attempt to partially apply the function with something like

```cpp
function<vector<int>(vector<int>)> take_2 = take(2);
```

I get the following error:

```
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
function<vector<T>(vector<T>)> take(int n) {
                               ^
```

Any help towards achieving this would be very much appreciated!

I am also very inexperienced with templates and lambdas in C++, so please let me know if there are more elegant ways to go about this.

Comment: C++ doesn't have polymorphic functions (templates aren't) or robust type inference. If you need Haskell, you know where to find it.

Comment: [Template instantiation can only deduce its parameters from the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32554529)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`take` is a function template with a non-deducible template parameter. Template parameters can be deduced from function arguments when corresponding function parameters depend on template parameters; but `int` does not depend on `T`.

In contrast to how type inference works in some other languages, C++ doesn't allow to deduce template parameters from the way a call result is used.

The only way to call `take` is to specify the template parameter explicitly, for example `take<std::string>(42)`.

A Rank 2 Haskell's function

```
take' :: int -> (forall a . [a] -> [a])
```

can be approximated with a C++ function that returns a function object (e.g. a lambda) with an `operator()` member template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

auto take(std::size_t n) {
   return [n](auto xs) {
     if (xs.size() > n)
       xs.resize(n);
     return x;
   };
}

auto show(const auto& xs) {
    for (const auto& x: xs) std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
};

int main()
{
   const auto take2 = take(2);
   show(take2(std::vector{1,2,3,4,5}));
   show(take2(std::vector{"a","b","c","d","e"}));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return an object with a templated call operator that can handle anything with a `resize` method and a copy/move constructor. A lambda function can do that:

```cpp
#include <deque>
#include <cstdio>

auto take(size_t n) {
    return [n](auto container) {
        container.resize(n);
        return container;
    };
}

int main() {
    auto take_2 = take(2);
    std::deque<int> d;
    auto d2 = take_2(d);
    std::printf("size of d2 is %zu\n", d2.size());
}
```